# proxy server's response and ping difference

Tags: linux, proxy

When using a proxy, site can ping the client and then get a difference between ping ms vs response ms. If the difference is too great then it means proxy is detected.

Question is how to fight fight against it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that sites use a latency difference to know if you use a proxy. They probably juste look for the X-Forwarded-For http header (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

Comment: Here: https://thesafety.us/check-ip
"Tunnel definition
(double-sided ping)"

Tells exactly the ms of a ping and ms of a client response

Comment: Here's a one solution but not the best one:
https://www.tecmint.com/block-ping-icmp-requests-to-linux/

Basically it block's a ping request so the webpage can't compare the ping time to client response time.

Perhaps it is possible to somehow delay ping response so the difference between them won't be that big to be detected as proxy or tunneling